# О повторе двоеточия

Tags: пунктуация

Под статьей в газете указаны телефоны автора. Но вопрос в том, может ли там повторяться двоеточие, если написано так:
*Телефоны:

Симферополь: (номера);

Севастополь: (номера)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему нет? Здесь все корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Как математик я такую вложенную структуру приветствую: она весьма четкая. Однако "на вид" немного смущает (как это, впрочем, часто бывает с формализованными структурами).

Интересно, как регулируется оформление краткой информации по канонам языка? Может, кто знает?